# Server Error- Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, log4net

I am trying to generate a crystal report on a website that i created using visual studio 2012. I installed the Support Pack 8 Executable from this site: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824 and integrted Crysital reports with my visual studio. I am able to generate the report on my computer, but when i moved my website to a different server I get an error. Initially i had errors about different .dll's missing, but after adding them it fixed the problem. I could not however get passed this one error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I found this log4net.dll on my computer and added it to my website on the server, but i can not get passed this error. it is a Windows 2008 Server running IIS 7. I am using ASP.net 4.0.

Is there a reference that i need to  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a duplicate of several similar questions, amongst which the consensus seems to be making sure that the installer for the correct target platform (x86 vs x64) is used.

See the following for more detail:

[Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291736/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-log4net-version-1-2-10-0-culture-neutral-pub)

[Log4net.dll + C# + Crystal Reports = error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776584/log4net-dll-c-sharp-crystal-reports-error)

[Crystal Reports error when deployed..Could not load file or assembly 'log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208516/crystal-reports-error-when-deployed-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-log4net?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

The issue was on IIS in which I set in the Advanced Settings of the AppPool the option "Enable 32 Bit Applications" to False and in that way the Crystal Runtime For 64 Bits worked perfectly without needing to install the 32 bit Runtime, and so on the whole application.