# Console App with Log4Net compiles in Debug but not in Release mode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, log4net

I have a simple C#/4.0 console app that reference Log4Net 1.2.13.0 in VS2010.

In debug mode the app compiles and runs fine on my machine. However, as soon as I change to 'Release' I get the error

> "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\mike\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\xxxx\yyyyy\log4net.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported."

In the AssemblyInfo.cs I have added the line:

`[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]`

According to the configuration mgr, but Debug and Release are set to use platform x86. This is also happening in another C# service application on my laptop, but I thought it easier if stick with getting it working here first.

The app.config file contains a section for:

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
```

Thanks in advance
Mike

Comment: How did you add log4net to your project? Might be worth a try to use the NuGet packetmanager to install Log4Net

Comment: Could this have something to do with it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753979/visual-studio-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-operation-is-not-supported-erro

Comment: I changed the app.config to this <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" /> and then it worked. Very frustrating that its not all obvious. Thanks guys

Comment: @mikcatta, if that was the solution for you, please add and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the type definition in the `app.config` to specify the fully qualified assembly name resolved the issue for me:

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" />
```

Comment: If you're going to mark your own answer as an answer, at least make your answer even minimally useful. Copying your comment above would probably help somebody else attempting to find a simalar answer.

Comment: @JackHughes: He forgot to mark his XML snippet as a code block so it was not visible. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue. I just checked the **[Unblock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML3ic.png)** checkbox at the properties of log4net.dll which resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).